# Redirect out of 'app' directory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have created a 'blog' directory on the same level as my 'app' directory in my CakePHP installation. The blog directory basically contains a WordPress blog.

However, when I redirect my users to www.domain.com/site/**blog**, CakePHP would automatically throw an error as there is no '**blog**' controller instead of redirecting them to the WordPress blog.

How do it redirect users out of the 'app' directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the folder containing app/ and blog/ , there should be a .htaccess file. There will be a section similar to this:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

change this so that the blog folder is ignored by CakePHP's rewriter rules:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^site/blog.*
   RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```